# Defining an equivalence relation

Tags: equivalence-relations

For the set $ \Bbb R$, define two elements in $ \Bbb R$ to be equivalent if their difference belongs to $ \Bbb Q$.

I can prove that this defines an equivalence relation. (see [Verify an equivalence relation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688487/verify-an-equivalence-relation))

However, I would like to be able to define the class and the partition.  Is it possible to place an element into a class without comparing it to other members of the class?

A similar problem, where the difference belongs to $ \Bbb Z$, any element r $\in \Bbb R$ can be classified by setting up class A<sub>m</sub> such that m = r - g(r) where g(r) returns the nearest integer less than r.  As a result, any r $\in \Bbb R$ can be put into some class A<sub>m</sub>, $0<=m<1$.  There may be other indexing schemes.

But I can't come up with anything for the difference belonging to $ \Bbb Q$.

This problem is from Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra.

thanks.

Comment: "I would like to be able to define the class and the partition" -- what do you mean by "the class"?

Comment: equivalence *classes* I presume

Comment: Pinter is the only author I'm familiar at all with - he states, "To partition a set _A_ is to separate the elements of _A_ into nonempty subsets ... which are called the _classes_ of the partition."

Comment: Yes classES plural. I figured out what you meant once I started writing my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:
$$
x \sim y \iff x - y=q \in \mathbb{Q}
$$
Consider the equivalence class of $0$, this is the set of real numbers $x$ such that $ x-0=q \in\mathbb{Q}$ so the class $[0]$ is the set of rational numbers.

Now consider an irrational number $z$, since $z-0$ is irrational we have $z\notin [0]$ (it is not rational), So it represents another equivalence class $[z]$ that contains all the irrational numbers $y$ such that $y=z+q$ with $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

For another irrational number $y \notin [z]$  ( i.e. $y-z \notin \mathbb{Q}$), we have another equivalence class $[y]$ .. and so on.

So, The equivalence classes are represented by $[0]$ and $[z_1],[z_2],\ldots$ where $z_i$ are all irrational numbers that differ by an irrational number, and there are uncountable infinitely many such classes.

Answer (score 1):

#### *1st example*

The equivalence relation is:
$$
x \sim y \iff x - y \in \mathbb{Q}
$$
For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $[x]_\sim$ be its equivalence class:
$$
[x]_{\sim} = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \sim y\}
$$

Then the partition, or quotient, is just:
$$
\mathbb{R}/\!\!\sim \; = \{[x]_{\sim} \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
Two reals $x, y$ are $\sim$-equivalent when their difference is a rational. Notice, then, that the equivalence class of $0$ is $\mathbb{Q}$: all rationals are $\sim$-equivalent and none are equivalent to any irrational. The equivalence class of $\pi$ is just $\{\pi + q \mid q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, and does not contain, for example, $e$, or $e + 17$. 
In general, the equivalence classes are of the form $r + \mathbb{Q} = \{r + q \mid q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Each equivalence class is countable, so there are uncountably many equivalence classes.

#### *2nd example*

Here, differences are in $\mathbb{Z}$, and every equivalence class has a unique representative in $[0,1)$. The equivalence class of $\frac 1 2$ is $\{\dots - \frac 3 2, -\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, \frac 3 2, \dots \}$; the equivalence class of $\pi$ is $\{\dots \pi - 4, \pi - 3, \pi - 2, \dots \}$.

Again, each equivalence class is countable, so there are uncountably many equivalence classes.

Comment: I think we're on the same page on the integer differences, you just put it much better than I did.  My point with it though was that it's possible to associate a unique representative for any given real number.  If r = 9.9987, then it goes into the equivalence class of 0.9987.  But I don't see any way to do that if the difference is a rational number.  All rational numbers go into the same equivalence class, but what designator would be used for, say, pi?  pi - 1, pi - 4.552, etc are all in the same equivalence class.

Comment: That's quite right, you can't, in the case of example 1. This "indiscernibility" of the equivalence classes is exploited in the construction of a nonmeasurable set. By the Axiom of Choice, there *is* a set that contains a unique representative for each equivalence class. This "choice set" is plucked out of thin air, you can't say anything about the representatives. A (any) set of representatives of this relation is called a [*Vitali set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). It's the standard example of a set that is not measurable.