# Equivalence relation on the real numbers per difference is rational

Tags: equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1480408/121890) an equivalence relation on the reals is described as

$$ x \sim y \iff x - y\in \mathbb{Q} \qquad \forall x, y\in \Bbb R$$

Denoting an equivalence class as $[x] := \{y\in\Bbb R \mid y\sim x\}$, the set of equivalence classes $T:= \{[x]\mid x\in \Bbb R\}$ forms a group with an addition defined on the representatives as $[x] + [y] := [x+y]$ with $\Bbb Q$ as the neutral element and $-[x] = [-x]$ the inverse.

Question(s): Does this structure have a name and some literature? For example, would it be possible to add a non-trivial multiplication to get to a ring or field? Is it helpful (in some non-trivial interpretation of "helpful" ;-) in some field of math?

Related: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1907599/121890) is about the equivalence relation defined by the quotient being rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) of the group $(\Bbb R,+)$ by the subgroup $\Bbb Q$. Usually it's indicated by $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$.